# JMETER 403 when uploading a file but needs to be logged in

Tags: jmeter

So I am trying to test the file upload function of this website: http://the-v.net/en/vtube/upload-video through JMETER but to be successful, the user has to be logged in through this form: http://the-v.net/login, Now, I think this is a parameter-based authentication which could be solved by defining a valid username and password in the HTTP Authorization Manager config element, but even doing so I keep getting this error:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-01-30 20:11:06 CST
Load time: 1373
Connect Time: 214
Latency: 1167
Size in bytes: 19151
Sent bytes:134
Headers size in bytes: 768
Body size in bytes: 18383
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 12:11:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=900
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Link: <http://the-v.net/en/vtube/warning>; rel="canonical",<http://the-v.net/en/vtube/warning>; rel="shortlink",<http://the-v.net/sites/all/themes/vtube17/favicon.png>; rel="shortcut icon"
Etag: "1517314266-0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 12:11:06 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Any idea on how can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you record the upload in the browser and look in View Results Tree the headers/ coookies that are transmitted.

You can use File > Template. > Recording

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

You are most probably missing:

- A header
- A cookie
- A parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to be **logged in** in order to be able to upload anything. HTTP Authorization Manager won't help as it is designed to deal with protocol level authentication and you need cookie-based one.

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Pay attention to [`form_build_id`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7.x) dynamic parameter you need to pass along with credentials during login request

   [image: Drupal Form Build ID jmeter]

So your test plan should look like:

- 1st HTTP Request - open login page

  - [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (i.e. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) to fetch `form_build_id`
- 2nd HTTP Request - perform login - provide credentials and the `form_build_id` from the previous step. You will also need to pass `form_id` parameter with the value of `MYFORM_form`
- 3rd HTTP Request - perform the upload.

Comment: Thanks! I recorded the whole login and upload processor and just manually edited the post HTTP request for upload..